Why am I getting an error while I'm trying to add to my liked songs?
I get a 400 error code when I try making an API request to add to my liked songs. I do not understand why I am getting it, as I am feeding the API request the track.id as the documentation suggests I do:
This is what I logged to the console.error:

"{"error": {"status": 400, "message": "Missing required field: id"

This is my home.jsx that I have set up to make put requests to add to liked songs on a users' spotify account once I press the heart button:
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { logout } from "../features/userSlice";
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useSwipeable } from "react-swipeable";
import { IoPlay, IoPause } from "react-icons/io5";
import { GoHeartFill } from "react-icons/go";
import { IoRemoveCircleOutline } from "react-icons/io5";
import {
    fetchSongRecommendations,
    songsRecommended,
    fetchTopArtists,
    topArtistsSelector,
    fetchNewReleases,
    newReleases,
    like,
    dislike,
    liked,
    disliked,
} from "../features/recommendationsSlice";
import { playTrack, pauseTrack } from "../features/playbackSlice";
import { user } from "../features/userSlice";

const Home = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const topArtists = useSelector(topArtistsSelector);
    const myRecommended = useSelector(songsRecommended);
    const newSongs = useSelector(newReleases);
    const playbackState = useSelector((state) => state.playback);
    const profile = useSelector(user);
    const likedTracks = useSelector(liked);
    const dislikedTracks = useSelector(disliked);

    // State to track the current song index
    const [currentSongIndex, setCurrentSongIndex] = useState(0);
    const currentTrack = myRecommended[currentSongIndex];

    // Check if the current track is liked
    const isTrackLiked = likedTracks.some((track) => track.id === currentTrack?.id);
    const isTrackDisliked = dislikedTracks.some((track) => track.id === currentTrack?.id);

    // Audio reference
    const audioRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchTopArtists());
    }, [dispatch]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (topArtists.length > 0) {
            dispatch(fetchSongRecommendations());
        }
    }, [dispatch, topArtists]);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchNewReleases());
    }, [dispatch]);

    // Swipe handlers
    const swipeHandlers = useSwipeable({
        onSwipedLeft: () => handleNextSong(),
        onSwipedRight: () => handlePreviousSong(),
        preventDefaultTouchmoveEvent: true,
        trackMouse: true,
    });

    // Play or pause track
    const handlePlayPause = () => {
        if (
            playbackState.isPlaying &&
            playbackState.currentTrack === currentTrack?.preview_url
        ) {
            dispatch(pauseTrack());
        } else {
            dispatch(playTrack(currentTrack?.preview_url));
        }
    };

    // Handle track change
    const handleNextSong = () => {
        if (currentSongIndex < myRecommended.length - 1) {
            setCurrentSongIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex + 1);
        }
    };

    const handlePreviousSong = () => {
        if (currentSongIndex > 0) {
            setCurrentSongIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex - 1);
        }
    };

    // Audio handling
    useEffect(() => {
        if (audioRef.current) {
            audioRef.current.pause(); // Pause current audio
        }

        audioRef.current = new Audio(currentTrack?.preview_url);
        if (playbackState.isPlaying) {
            audioRef.current.play();
        }

        return () => {
            audioRef.current.pause();
            audioRef.current.src = "";
        };
    }, [currentTrack, playbackState.isPlaying]);

    const handleLike = () => {
        dispatch(like(currentTrack)); // Dispatch like action
    };

    const handleDislike = () => {
        dispatch(dislike(currentTrack)); // Dispatch dislike action
    };

    return (
        <div className="p-5 grid gap-10">
            <h1 className="text-center text-xl">
                <span className="font-bold">Welcome</span> {profile?.display_name} to Jammin, your AI-enhanced music assistant!
            </h1>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-2">
                <h2>Song recommendations</h2>
                <button className="justify-self-end border rounded-lg p-1">Enhance</button>
            </div>
            <div
                className="border rounded-lg overflow-hidden w-full grid grid-rows-[90%_10%] h-[400px]"
                {...swipeHandlers}
            >
                <div key={currentSongIndex} className="grid justify-items-center">
                    <img
                        src={currentTrack?.album.images[1]?.url}
                        alt={currentTrack?.name}
                    />
                    <p>{currentTrack?.name}</p>
                    <p className="opacity-50 text-[12px]">
                        {currentTrack?.artists.map((artist) => artist?.name).join(", ")}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div className="grid grid-cols-3 justify-items-center border-t">
                    <button onClick={handleDislike}>
                        <IoRemoveCircleOutline className={`h-full ${isTrackDisliked ? "text-red-500" : ""}`} size={28} />
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={handlePlayPause}>
                        {playbackState.isPlaying && playbackState.currentTrack === currentTrack?.preview_url ? (
                            <IoPause className="h-full" size={28} />
                        ) : (
                            <IoPlay className="h-full" size={28} />
                        )}
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={handleLike}>
                        <GoHeartFill className={`h-full ${isTrackLiked ? "text-green" : ""}`} size={28} />
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="grid gap-2">
                <h2>New Releases:</h2>
                {newSongs?.albums?.items.map((song) => (
                    <div key={song.id} className="border rounded-lg overflow-hidden grid grid-cols-[20%_80%] gap-2">
                        <img src={song.images[1].url} alt={song.name} />
                        <div className="grid content-center">
                            <p>{song.artists.map((artist) => artist.name).join(", ")}</p>
                            <p className="opacity-50 text-[12px]">{song.name} - {song.type}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch(logout())} className="bg-red-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded">
                Logout
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;


Below is the recommendationsSlice.jsx where the actual API call has been made. I do not understand why it keeps throwing the 400 error since everything seems in order. Is there something I'm missing?
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import SpotifyWebApi from 'spotify-web-api-js';

const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();

const initialState = {
  tracks: [],
  likedTracks: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('liked_tracks')) || [],
  dislikedTracks: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('disliked_tracks')) || [],
  topArtists: [],
  newReleases: [],
  status: 'idle',
  error: null,
};

// Fetch song recommendations
export const fetchSongRecommendations = createAsyncThunk(
  'recommendations/fetchSongRecommendations',
  async (_, { rejectWithValue, getState }) => {
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    if (!accessToken) {
      return rejectWithValue('No access token found.');
    }

    const state = getState();
    const topArtists = state.recommendations.topArtists;
    if (!topArtists || topArtists.length === 0) {
      return rejectWithValue('No top artists available for recommendations.');
    }

    try {
      spotifyApi.setAccessToken(accessToken);
      const artistSeeds = topArtists.map((artist) => artist.id).slice(0, 5);

      const response = await spotifyApi.getRecommendations({
        seed_artists: artistSeeds,
        limit: 40,
      });

      if (!response || !response.tracks) {
        return rejectWithValue('Invalid response from Spotify API.');
      }

      const tracksWithPreviews = response.tracks.filter((track) => track.preview_url);
      const limitedTracks = tracksWithPreviews.slice(0, 20);
      return limitedTracks;
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.status === 429) {
        const retryAfter = error.headers['retry-after'] || 1;
        return rejectWithValue(`Rate limit hit. Retry after ${retryAfter} seconds.`);
      }
      return rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
);

// Fetch top artists
export const fetchTopArtists = createAsyncThunk(
  'recommendations/fetchTopArtists',
  async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    if (!accessToken) {
      return rejectWithValue('No access token found.');
    }

    try {
      spotifyApi.setAccessToken(accessToken);
      const response = await spotifyApi.getMyTopArtists();

      const topArtists = response.items.slice(0, 5).map((artist) => ({
        id: artist.id,
        name: artist.name,
      }));

      return topArtists;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
);

// Fetch new releases
export const fetchNewReleases = createAsyncThunk(
  'recommendations/fetchNewReleases',
  async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    if (!accessToken) {
      return rejectWithValue('No access token found.');
    }

    try {
      spotifyApi.setAccessToken(accessToken);
      const response = await spotifyApi.getNewReleases({ limit: 10 });
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
);

// Like a track
export const like = createAsyncThunk(
  'recommendations/like',
  async (track, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    if (!accessToken) {
      return rejectWithValue('No access token found.');
    }

    try {
      spotifyApi.setAccessToken(accessToken);
      let likedTracks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('liked_tracks')) || [];

      const trackIndex = likedTracks.findIndex((likedTrack) => likedTrack.id === track.id);
      if (trackIndex > -1) {
        await spotifyApi.removeFromMySavedTracks([track.id]);
        const updatedLikedTracks = likedTracks.filter((likedTrack) => likedTrack.id !== track.id);
        localStorage.setItem('liked_tracks', JSON.stringify(updatedLikedTracks));
        return updatedLikedTracks;
      } else {
        await spotifyApi.addToMySavedTracks([track.id]);
        const updatedLikedTracks = [...likedTracks, track];
        localStorage.setItem('liked_tracks', JSON.stringify(updatedLikedTracks));
        return updatedLikedTracks;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
);

// Dislike a track
export const dislike = createAsyncThunk(
  'recommendations/dislike',
  async (track, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    if (!accessToken) {
      return rejectWithValue('No access token found.');
    }

    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(accessToken);
    let dislikedTracks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('disliked_tracks')) || [];
    let likedTracks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('liked_tracks')) || [];

    const trackIndex = dislikedTracks.findIndex((dislikedTrack) => dislikedTrack.id === track.id);
    const likedTrackIndex = likedTracks.findIndex((likedTrack) => likedTrack.id === track.id);

    try {
      if (likedTrackIndex > -1) {
        likedTracks = likedTracks.filter((likedTrack) => likedTrack.id !== track.id);
        await spotifyApi.removeFromMySavedTracks([track.id]);
        localStorage.setItem('liked_tracks', JSON.stringify(likedTracks));
      }

      if (trackIndex > -1) {
        dislikedTracks = dislikedTracks.filter((dislikedTrack) => dislikedTrack.id !== track.id);
      } else {
        dislikedTracks = [...dislikedTracks, track];
      }

      localStorage.setItem('disliked_tracks', JSON.stringify(dislikedTracks));
      return dislikedTracks;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
);

const recommendationsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'recommendations',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},

  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchSongRecommendations.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'loading';
      })
      .addCase(fetchSongRecommendations.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'succeeded';
        state.tracks = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(fetchSongRecommendations.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'failed';
        state.error = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(fetchTopArtists.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'loading';
      })
      .addCase(fetchTopArtists.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.topArtists = action.payload;
        state.status = 'succeeded';
      })
      .addCase(fetchTopArtists.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'failed';
        state.error = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(fetchNewReleases.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'loading';
      })
      .addCase(fetchNewReleases.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.newReleases = action.payload;
        state.status = 'succeeded';
      })
      .addCase(fetchNewReleases.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'failed';
        state.error = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(like.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.likedTracks = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(dislike.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.dislikedTracks = action.payload;
      });
  },
});

export default recommendationsSlice.reducer;

// Selectors
export const fetchStatus = (state) => state.recommendations.status;
export const songsRecommended = (state) => state.recommendations.tracks;
export const topArtistsSelector = (state) => state.recommendations.topArtists;
export const newReleasesSelector = (state) => state.recommendations.newReleases;
export const likedTracksSelector = (state) => state.recommendations.likedTracks;
export const dislikedTracksSelector = (state) => state.recommendations.dislikedTracks;


The error is suggesting that the track id is missing and I do not see how that is as I make the request with it.

Does the track have an incorrect id? Like not null or undefined?

Hi there when I actually log the ID before the call is made I see that a song id is present so the id is not null or undefined it is actually the song id

There is way to much code in your question. Reduce your code to only show the request that is failing (or at least clearly point out where in your code it's failing). And if the API response tells you, "missing data" there is no point in insisting the data is there. It isn't. Either because the property does not have a value or because you are using it wrong. But nobody is willing to go through hundets of lines of code to eventually find, which request is failing

It also seems you are using an unoffical wrapper around the spotify API which was last updated 3 years ago. Maybe it's just not building the correct request? Because for instance for the addToMySavedTracks request the offical Spotify docs require an ids: string[] parameter in the request body (or url parameters). I don't see that happening anywhere in in that wrapper

Use the network inspector and check the failing request if it contains all necessary data
